# Why do we need q=$uri in nginx configuration for wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm trying to understand why in many nginx configuration examples people use `q=$uri&$args`. For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

I'm interesting in it because for one of installed plugins "q" parameter isn't in white list and nginx has such configuration. Can I just use `/index.php?$args;` intead? Can this affect some hidden functionality?

**P.S.** I have WP v5.3.2 and my theme doesn't use such parameter

Comment: I am not WP expert, but it seems like pretty url routing, Without `?q=` you will not know what item you try to reach

Comment: The `q` parameter isn't needed in modern WordPress implementations. The [Nginx recipe](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/) suggests the `$args` parameter is only needed for non-standard permalink support. Personally, I use neither.